# Getting distinct pairs from one table column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get a unique pair of values from a query in Oracle which basically looks like this:

```
 select a.name, b.name 
 from table1 a
 join table1 b on a.attribute = b.attribute
```

Now this should give me a bunch of repeated values like

- apple,banana
- orange,kiwi
- banana,apple
- kiwi,orange

but instead I just get

- apple,apple
- banana, banana
- kiwi, kiwi
- orange, orange

when I add

```
 select a.name, b.name 
 from table1 a
 join table1 b on a.attribute = b.attribute
 where a.attribute < b.attribute
```

I get "No rows selected"

and I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please please help

Comment: You probably need `where a.name < b.name` - just think about what you are trying to achieve to understand why this is the right condition, not the one you had in your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit joining the same name by using a.name <> b.name

```
select a.name, b.name from table1 a
join table1 b
on a.name <> b.name
```

Comment: Thank you I could not find that anywhere

Answer (score 1):

It seems that same attributes in both tables correspond to same names.
If you use

```
on a.attribute != b.attribute
```

you will get every possible pair of different names.
If you still get pairs of same names you can add

```
where a.name != b.name
```

Is that what you need?